# capture android app http traffic

Tags: android, linux, http, capture, wireshark

I need to see what http calls are made by a specific android app I have on my device (not rooted).

Do you have any idea on what the easiest solution would be ?

I have a local wlan and a ubuntu laptop, could I somehow capture the http traffic of my phone via my laptop ? (I've tried running wireshark, but I only see the traffic of my laptop)

Thanks for any help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest option I can think of is this:
Connect your laptop to the router via Ethernet. Create an ad-hoc network with your laptop's wireless card, forwarding all traffic out the Ethernet. Have the android device connect to the ad-hoc network. Wireshark away.
Second idea: The basic problem is that your wireless router doesn't broadcast the data to all the ports / wireless connections. I'm also going to assume that the router won't let you forward data to another connection. So, what you really need here is a hub.
So if you have a hub, and you can put it between the WAN side of the router and the network connection, then you can plug your laptop into the hub. As a hub will broadcast data to all of its ports, you should now be able to use wireshark.
Having said all that, this probably belongs on superuser.com.

Comment: Great idea, I'm gonna try that and let you know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that android does not support ad-hoc networks (at least version 1.5 on my non-rooted device)

Comment: I finally solved the issue by rooting the device and running tcpdump on it. Thanks for the tip anyway ;)